# Identifying (and removing) sequences from a vector in Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to prune any sequence of length 3 or more from a vector of numbers in Matlab (or Octave).  For example, given the vector *dataSet*,

```
dataSet = [1 2 3 7 9 11 13 17 18 19 20 22 24 25 26 28 30 31];
```

removing all sequences of length 3 or more would yield prunedDataSet:

```
prunedDataSet = [7 9 11 13 22 28 30 31 ];
```

I can brute force a solution, but I suspect there is a more succinct (and perhaps efficient) way to do it using vector/matrix operations, but I always get confused about whether something yields an index or the value at said index.  Suggestions?

Here's the brute force method I came up with:

```
dataSet = [1 2 3 7 9 11 13 17 18 19 20 22 24 25 26 28 30 31];
benign = [];
for i = 1:size(dataSet,2)-2;
    if (dataSet(i) == (dataSet(i+1)-1) && dataSet(i) == dataSet(i+2)-2);
        benign = [benign i ] ;
    end;
end;

remove = [];
for i = 1:size(benign,2);
    remove = [remove benign(i) benign(i)+1 benign(i)+2 ];
end;

remove = unique(remove);

prunedDataSet = setdiff(dataSet, dataSet(remove));
```

Comment: You need to be more precise about what you mean by _any sequence of length 3_... do you mean only `k,k+1,k+2` for any `k` or can `k,k-1,k-2` also be included? what about `k,±m,k±2m` or for that matter, geometric sequences like `k,k^2,k^3` or `k,k*a,k*a^2`, etc?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious from the dataSet/prunedDataSet and definitive with the "brute force method" that I gave: k, k+1, k+2.

Comment: I understood your example. However, what was not clear was the term _any sequence_ in the first line. Anyway, I guess you do have good solutions below, so no worries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution using [DIFF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diff.html) and [STRFIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html)

```
%# define dataset
dataSet = [1 2 3 7 9 11 13 17 18 19 20 22 24 25 26 28 30 31];

%# take the difference. Whatever is part of a sequence will have difference 1
dds = diff(dataSet);

%# sequences of 3 lead to two consecutive ones. Sequences of 4 are like two sequences of 3
seqIdx = findstr(dds,[1 1]);

%# remove start, start+1, start+2
dataSet(bsxfun(@plus,seqIdx,[0;1;2])) = []
dataSet =

     7     9    11    13    22    28    30    31
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an attempt using vector-matrix notation:

```
s1 = [(dataSet(1:end-1) == dataSet(2:end)-1), false];
s2 = [(dataSet(1:end-2) == dataSet(3:end)-2), false, false];
s3 = s1 & s2;
s = s3 | [false, s3(1:end-1)] | [false, false, s3(1:end-2)];
dataSet(~s)
```

The idea is: `s1` is true for all positions where a number `a` appears before `a+1`. `s2` is true for all positions where `a` appears two positions before `a+2`. Then `s` becomes true where both the previous conditions are met. Then, we build `s` such that every true value is propagated to its two successors.

Finally, `dataSet(~s)` keeps all the values for which the above conditions are false, that is, it keeps numbers that are not part of a 3-sequence.