# Filter islands based on length in a binary array - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a binary array and I would like to flip values based on the length which they repeat. as an example

```
Ar = [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1];
```

Ideally I would like to flip the 1's which repeat only 2 or fewer times resulting in the following.

```
Ar = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1];
```

From what I have located online, the [Diff](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function is most commenly used to locate and remove sequences. But from what I have [located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157680/identifying-and-removing-sequences-from-a-vector-in-matlab-octave#6159092), it appears to target all instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [`imopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) from Image Processing toolbox with a kernel of `3` `ones` -

```
imopen(Ar,[1,1,1])
```

Sample run -

```
>> Ar = [0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1];
>> out = imopen(Ar,[1,1,1]);
>> [Ar(:) out(:)]
ans =
     0     0
     1     0
     0     0
     0     0
     0     0
     1     0
     1     0
     0     0
     0     0
     0     0
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     0     0
     0     0
     0     0
     0     0
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
```

Vectorized solution without using I.P. toolbox -

```
function out = filter_islands_on_length(Ar, n)
out = Ar;
a = [0 Ar 0];
d = diff(a);
r = find(d);

s0 = r(1:2:end);
s1 = r(2:2:end);

id_arr = zeros(1,numel(Ar));
m = (s1-s0) <= n;

id_arr(s0(m)) = 1;
id_arr(s1(m)) = -1;
out(cumsum(id_arr)~=0) = 0;
```

Sample runs -

```
>> Ar
Ar =
     0     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1
>> filter_islands_on_length(Ar, 2)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
>> filter_islands_on_length(Ar, 1)
ans =
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     1
```

Comment: This was actually the first thing I thought of doing so thumbs up for thinking of the same solution. I was worried however that this would be a roundabout way of doing something simpler.

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf Could you explain "simpler" how?

Comment: I guess simple is the wrong word. I'm worried about pulling in different matlab toolboxes to accomplish a task as not everyone who uses my code would potentially have the image processing toolbox. I'm trying to find a solution which uses the base. However if their isn't then this is the best option.

Comment: @Hojo.Timberwolf Check out the new solution at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution requiring no toolbox but needs Matlab 2016a or later:

```
n = 3; % islands shorter than n will be removed
Ar = movmax(movsum(Ar,n),[ceil(n/2-1) floor(n/2)])==n;
```